# Database Suggestion for a social network app using Parse Server

Tags: database, database-design, parse-server

Need suggestion for database for our social network app

So we have a "GroupChat" class where we have an array of "_Users" class objects.

Now in this "_Users" array we want to add invited user aswell.

Example: "John" is a user who invited "Dave/dave@blah.com" but dave is yet to sign up.

But when we open the GroupChat and see the list of users, it should include the invited users as well.

So we are wondering if we should 
1.create a new class "InvitedUsers" for invited users or 
2.we should directly add invited users to "_Users" class with a flag signedUp=false. And when they signup we check if they already exists and overwrite the data.

Now Problems,

1. if we create new class "InvitedUsers" then we will have to fetch both the classes everytime which is make the app a bit slow
2. if we create these invited users directly into user class then parse-server automatically sends email to newly created users(which we dont want to until they sign up)
3. if we create these invited users directly into user class then we will have to check if the invited user already exists before signing up, if exists then just overwrite. which is doable without any problem?

Thanks

Comment: The first problem isn't a problem.  Create an InvitedUsers class.

Answer (score 0):

Your question has 2 votes to close as primarily opinion based by now. And indeed the answer is, whatever you like more.

To address your "problems":

1. I really don't see why this would make your app a bit slower
2. Well, why don't you adjust your parsing so that the signedUp=false is considered?
3. Why on earth should that be a problem? That's what databases do all day. Either do it in a transaction, or if your dbms has a built-in functionality use it (like MySQL's `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`)

Comment: 1. We will have to fetch InvitedUser to show in group chat users, while if we use user class, no need to fetch data from 2 classes.
2. yes signedUp=false seems good, and on login/sign up we just fill the data instead of creating new user
3. yes same thing as 2